# How to highlight features with same property in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, gis

I have a map with many polygons stored in a GeoJSON file. I want to display these polygons on the map whereby polygons with the same feature 'BROAD_CATEGORY' are highlighted on mouseover on the map legend.

The only examples and documentation I have seen to do this relate to number values rather than text strings (e.g. [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206769/hover-on-legend-to-highlight-multiple-areas-on-map)).

This is my legend code for the map at the moment:

```
    var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
legend.onAdd = function (map) {

    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
        labels = ['<strong>Language(s) of Origin</strong>'],
        categories = ['Aboriginal clan','Action','Body part','Colour','Function of place','Historic event or place','Industry','Local estate','Nature','Other local places','Person','Place outside Australia','Portmanteau','Ship','Unknown'];

    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {

        div.innerHTML += 
        labels.push(
            '<i class="circle" style="background:' + getColor(categories[i]) + '"></i> ' +
        (categories[i] ? categories[i] : '+'));
    }
    
    div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
  
return div;
};
legend.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your geojson?

Comment: @kboul Sure, here's a sample: https://pastebin.com/ET7tE3eY